# RedisInsight Docker displaying: site cannot be reached in browser

Tags: docker, redis, redislabs

I'm new to Redis/RedisInsight and Docker.

I have windows 8. I'm trying to use RedisInsight via docker. I'm running following command.

```
docker run -v redisinsight:/db -p 8001:8001 redislabs/redisinsight
```

as mentioned in this tutorial.
https://docs.redislabs.com/latest/ri/installing/install-docker/

I assume I'm getting the correct console output displayed in the docker terminal.

[image]

but when I hit the mentioned URL in browser, I'm getting

[image]

I'm surely missing some step, can someone kindly guide me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the help of a friend, I was able to resolve this issue. Instead of using

> 0.0.0.0:8001

I entered

> 192.168.99.100:8001 (IP on which my docker was running)

and I was able to access redisInsight Terminal.

Answer (score 2):

RedisInsight is also available as a windows application. You can download it from the website: http://redislabs.com/redisinsight/

It's not an issue that I have seen with the Docker distribution. What is the version of Docker you are using?

It might be related to the volume mount, give a try with (to see if anything better):
`docker run --rm -p 8001:8001 redislabs/redisinsight`